# sh.exe": /bin/git bad file number when git -version

Tags: windows, git

Just installed git and when I run the git bash and enter git -version I get this error: `sh.exe": /bin/git: bad file number`.

During the installation I had one error but the installation proceeded :"unable to configure the line ending conversion core.autocrif true." Git GUI isn't launching and I get the error : "Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item." Trying to run as admin doesn't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run into this problem occasionally (including about 5 minutes ago) and I "solve" it by re-installing the [Git client](http://git-scm.com/downloads).